# How to allow no body in GET request while using flask-restful's reqparse.RequestParser?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-requests, flask-restful

I have a Flask_restful resource which I am adding as blueprint resource

```py
class SampleAPI(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)
        self.reqparse.add_argument('name', type=str, required=False,
                                   help='No name provided',
                                   location='json')
        
        self.reqparse.add_argument('id', type=str, required=False,
                                   help='No id provided',
                                   location='args')

    def post(self):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        name = args["name"]
        # Do something with name

        return lf.to_json(), 201

    def get(self):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        ID = args["id"]
        # Do something with ID

        return lf.to_json(), 200
```

When I use post endpoint, every works fine as I am sending a JSON body with request. BUT when I make a GET request, I get a bad request error -

```json
{
    "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
}
```

I found out that, I need to send an empty JSON body - "{}" with the request to make the request working otherwise it throws the bad request error as above.

I need to understand how I can allow `no body` but also use `reqparse.RequestParser` and parse arguments using flask_restful extension of flask in this GET request!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the get request, the body is not present, but `self.reqparse.parse_args()` tries to access it to verify the correctness of the passed parameters (it accesses it since at the moment of its creation it is specified that the parameter **name** is contained in the json body). In a get request, the parameters are passed inside the url and not the body, consequently the error is generated.

I advise you to create two different objects:

One for the post request, when you need to get your params from the json body:

```
self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)
self.reqparse.add_argument('name', type=str, required=False,
                                   help='No name provided',
                                   location='json')
```

And one for the get request, when you need to get your params from args:
when you need to get your params from the json body:

```
self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)
self.reqparse.add_argument('id', type=str, required=False,
                               help='No id provided',
                               location='args')
```

If you need both parameters in both requests, then create two different objects of type `RequestParser`, and add the two required parameters to both, specifying as location `'json'` in the case of the post request, and `'args'` in the case of the get request

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. But I have observed that while using python2 (older versions of these libraries), this issues does not occur meaning you will not get an error if don't send a JSON body with GET request. I was hoping that we could enable/disable a flag and this would resolve, but I guess that is not possible with latest libraries.

Comment: Also, for `GET` requests, make sure that `parse_args` argument `strict` is `False` (which is the default value). If True, RequestParser will parse the body (which is empty) as JSON thus fail with 415. Use `args = parser.parse_args(strict=False)`